# How to test if defined macro is empty at compile time (Cbjective-C / c)?

Tags: objective-c, c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to do check if I've got an empty define? IS_EMPTY_OR_UNDEFINED is a fictive macro I just came up with.

```
#define constantA 0
#define constantB 1
#define constantC null
#define constantF ""
#define constantH 

#if IS_EMPTY_OR_UNDEFINED(constantA)
# error constantA is defined 0 and the above if should not be true - this line should not run
#endif

#if IS_EMPTY_OR_UNDEFINED(constantB)
# error constantB is defined 1 and the above if should not be true - this line should not run
#endif

#if IS_EMPTY_OR_UNDEFINED(constantC)
# error constantC is defined null and the above if should not be true - this line should not run
#endif

#if IS_EMPTY_OR_UNDEFINED(constantF)
# error constantF is defined "" and the above if should not be true - this line should not run
#endif

#if ! IS_EMPTY_OR_UNDEFINED(constantH)
# error constantH is defined empty and the above if should not be true - this line should not run
#endif

#if defined(undefinedConstant) && ! IS_EMPTY_OR_UNDEFINED(undefinedConstant)
# error undefinedConstant is not defined and the above if should not be true - this line should not run
#endif
```

Comment: you can't do casts in the preprocessor. The preprocessor only has two types that it understands one for signed and the other for unsigned integer constants constants. These types correspond to what is know in other phases of the compiler as `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`.

Comment: Well it compiles and all my tests works fine.. Very strange..

Comment: if `constantA` starts with a `+` or `-` sign you could perhaps get away with it, because the `(int)` is in fact a `0` for the preprocessor. But if `constantA` is an integer constant the cast wouldn't serve anything. So why do you do this?

Comment: Ok. Yes, you are right. It was not working properly. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking if an expression is empty can be done (modulo some really exotic border case) but the technique is somewhat complicated. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) has a macro that does this and which you could be using as

```
#if !defined(constantA) || P99_IS_EMPTY(constantA)
...
#endif
```

Combining this in one single macro is not allowed by the C standard. AS of C11 6.10.1 p4, the token `defined` is not allowed inside macros or other expressions.

Comment: Ok. Cool. I'm sure it would work if the constant were declared normally.. I have declared it as a preproccessor macro.

Comment: @hfossli, not sure what you mean. But if you really want to have conditional compilation, this *can* only work when you have your constants defined as macros. Identifier tokens that are unknown in the preprocessing phase evaluate to `0` inside `#if` conditionals.

Comment: Ok. Now I tried with the P99 library. I downloaded it from http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/ . I had to comment out # include <stdnoreturn.h> since it was not found. It worked perfectly!

Comment: Terrific! Thanks! Results can be seen here. No errors were givven. See example here http://pastie.org/5684600#

Comment: @hfossli, great that it worked. Could you please send a bugreport for the `stdnoreturn.h` issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `#ifdef MACRO` or `#if defined(MACRO)` to test if macros are defined at all. You can also compare them, although only against integers:

```
#if MACRO > 5
```

etc. Maybe this helps you?

Edit: Although I don't know how you would check if a definition evaluates to "empty", or if this is possible.

Comment: I think just `#if MACRO` will check for definedness and non-emptiness.

Comment: I'm pretty certain `#if MACRO == ""` doesn't work. You can't do pre-processor comparisons against strings, see the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/cpp/ifstrcmp.html).

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin #ifdef checks if defined, #if checks for integer values >0.

Comment: Yep.. I get this error when doing #if MACRO == "": Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression

Comment: Didn't know that, never used it that way apparently. Edited the answer.